# How to split one variable into multiple rows

Tags: sas

```
**Application_id                Reaon_code            Value** 
123                              AB31AB45                £500
124                              AB43RD49TY87            £640
125                              RT87                    £900
126                              CD19RV29               £1000
```

What I want to get is separate the `reason_code` variable by taking the subset of this, each reason only has 4 character and combine 2 letters and 2 numbers, always

The dataset I want to get is the following:

```
Application_id             Reason_code                       Value 
123                             AB31                          £500 
123                             AB45                          £500
124                             AB43                          £640
124                             RD49                          £640
124                             TY87                          £640
145                             RT87                          £900
```

Hope this make sense.

2nd question, I want to create a flag showing:

```
Application_id             Reason_code               Value           Waterfall_reason                                                           Unique_Reason
123                             AB31                          £500                       1 (as it his AB31 first)                              0 (as it hits both AB31 and AB45)
123                             AB45                          £500                       0 (as it hits AB31 first)                             0 (as it hits both AB31 and AB45)
124                             AB43                         £640                        1 (as it hits AB43 first)                             0 (as it hits both AB43,RD49 and TY87)
124                             RD49                         £640                        0                                                            0
124                            TY87                           £640                        0                                                            0
145                            RT87                          £900                        1 (as it hits RT87 first)                              1 (as it ONLY Hit RT87)
```

Comment: Hi skybook - please show what you have tried so far to clarify your thinking and what may be helpful to others - rather than just listing requirements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 Data have;
 informat Application_id   $3.              Reaon_code $100.           Value NLMNLGBP.;
 input Application_id                Reaon_code            Value;
 Format Value NLMNLGBP.;
cards;

123                              AB31AB45                £500
124                              AB43RD49TY87            £640
125                              RT87                    £900
126                              CD19RV29               £1000
 ; 
Data Want;
 format Application_id   $3.              Reason_code $4.           Value     NLMNLGBP.;
 set have;
 OrigCode = Reaon_Code;
 Keep Application_id   Reason_code   Value ;
 Do Start = 1 to 25 by 4;* an arbitrary high number;* you could use a do while or a do until, also.;
     Reason_code = Substr( Reaon_Code , start ,   4 ) ;
     if reason_code = '' then leave;
      output;
  end;

 run;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that all codes a 4 characters then a simple DO loop will do the job.  Just keep taking the first four characters until the string is empty. If you create a variable of only length 4 and assign a longer string to it then just the first four characters will fit.  You can then remove the first four characters before the next time through the loop by using SUBSTR() function.

```
data have ;
  input ID Reason_Code :$20. Value ;
cards;
123 AB31AB45 500
124 AB43RD49TY87 640
125 RT87 900
126 CD19RV29 1000
;;;;
data want ;
  set have (rename=(reason_code=reason_list));
  length Reason_code $4 Waterfall_reason 8 Unique_reason 8;
  unique_reason = length(reason_list)<= 4;
  waterfall_reason= 1;
  do until (reason_list=' ');
    reason_code = reason_list ;
    output;
    waterfall_reason=0;
    reason_list = substr(reason_list,5);
  end;
run;
```

Comment: could you explain a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using Regular Expression, based on a different assumption that your substring is based on letters + digits, instead of a fixed 4-char setup. The code below will pick up strings fitting the pattern of letters + digits (in this case will include 2 letters + 2 digits), one after another, until the whole length of the input string is exhausted. 'waterfall_reason' is flagged only after the first substring is picked, and 'unique_reason' is done by countw() using alphabetic letter as delimiter.

```
data have;
    input ID Reason_Code :$20. Value;
    cards;
123 ABcd31AB45 500
124 AB43RD49T87 640
125 RT87 900
126 C19RV29 1000
;;;;

data want;
    set have;
    _pat=prxparse('/[a-z]+[0-9]+/io');
    _start=1;
    _stop=length(reason_code);
    unique_reason=ifn(countw(reason_code,,'a')=1,1,0);

    do _n=1 by 1 until (_pos = 0);
        call prxnext(_pat,_start,_stop,reason_code,_pos,_len);
        new_code=substr(reason_code,_pos, _len);
        waterfall_reason=ifn(_n=1,1,0);

        if not missing (new_code) then
            output;
    end;

    drop _:;
run;
```

Comment: Is it not necessary to define `_pos` somewhere?